# Dustjs eq filter, diffrent behavior on null and false

Tags: javascript, dust.js

I have data set like this:

```
[{"val": false}, {"val": null}]
```

And template:

```
{#.}
{@eq key=val type="string" value="false"}
FALSE
{:else}
NULL
{/eq}
{/.}
```

This template return: NULLNULL, but I want get FALSENULL. Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 5):

Any helper parameter that is not surrounded by quotes will be considered a reference. Consider this example:

JSON:

```
{
   "false":"mypropertyWithNameFalse"
}
```

and template

```
{@eq key=false type="string" value="mypropertyWithNameFalse"}
same
{:else}
not same
{/eq}
```

Dust will grab value of `false` key from context and as a result will render `same`.

In order for your example to work you'll need to pass in `false` in as a string and use `type="boolean"` parameter on `eq` helper like so:

```
{@eq key=val value="false" type="boolean"}
```

In this case values of `key` and `value` parameters will be coerced to boolean type and you'll get the result you are looking for.

Alternatively you could do `type="string"` to convert and compare values as strings. But there seems to be an issue with `coerce` not coercing falsy values. I think that's a bug and it needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working as I expected. Dust templates haven't got support for simple types like that:

```
{@eq key=val type="boolean" value=false}
```

When I use it that way:

```
{@eq key=val type="boolean" value="false"}
```

It works.